# Print PDF Text without color background

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

I am facing the following problem:

[image: This gray box is making me lose my mind.]

See the gray rectangle under the text? I want to remove it when printing this page.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You may be able to do this in Printer Settings, eg by printing in two-colour (black and white) mode. It depends on whether the printer driver allows you to set the black/white threshold. You could try other PDF readers instead of Acrobat.

Comment: Do you want to print one page or the entire document with multiple pages?

Answer (score 0):

There is no print setting that will suppress that color or not print it.  It's part of the content.  If you want a version without it, you would need to modify the content.

Depending on the PDF and how the content is stored, it may be possible to open the file in a document editor that handles PDFs, and change or eliminate the shading.  You may be able to export the content as a text file, which would remove all advanced formatting (this would probably require a lot of manual "rehabilitation" to restore some of the text structure/layout).

You also could likely use an image editor (like Photoshop, or another editor that can work with PDF files) to remove it.  As Hannu commented, removing it (or at least making it less noticeable) is not necessarily complicated.  Adjusting contrast and brightness, or color curves, will do most of what you need.  Note that in removing the background color in this way, you will also tend to removed fill used to make the characters appear less jagged.

Regardless of how you remove the shading, it isn't something that can be done with a print-time setting.  There is still a requirement to modify the content before printing it.

Comment: The majority of the background MAY be disappear with adjustment of Contrast and Brightness levels. www.gimp.org may be just as good at this.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously you can change the page background and text color as well.
Go to Preferences (press Ctrl+K) and select Accessibility. Under custom color change background to white. Voila!